# Tomcat that hosts the sync server crashes often when I sync Android SQlite with MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, tomcat, synchronization

I installed Tomcat 7.0.27 64-bit on my Windows host and deployed Pervasync data sync server to Tomcat to sync SQLite DB on Android tablets with a central Microsoft SQL server. It worked great initially but sometime Tomcat just crashes randomly. From the Tomcat log I saw this:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000001800057c0, pid=2476, tid=336
#
# JRE version: 7.0-b147
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [tcnative-1.dll+0x57c0]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: C:\MySoftwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.27-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\bin\hs_err_pid2476.mdmp
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\MySoftwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.27-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\bin\hs_err_pid2476.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Is this really a bug in the JVM or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More often than not, Tomcat crashes were caused by JNI libs. Pervasync is pure Java. So first thing to check is whether you were loading Tomcat Native library. See if you have something like the following in Catalinna*.log:

```
Apr 02, 2013 3:07:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.27 using APR version 1.4.6.
```

Maybe the binary you downloaded was not compatible with your hardware. Either re-compile the lib or switch to non-native -- remove the libs from Tomcat path.

Check out http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/ for more info on Apache Tomcat Native library.

Comment: I remove the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library and Tomcat stopped crashing.